# Slice appending not working as intended when generating a binary sequence

Tags: go

I have this piece of code that generate all binary sequences of length n.
so:

```
allBitsSeqs(2) gives a 1-by-n int slice  [[1 1][0 0] [1 0] [0 1]]
```

Here's the code:

```
func allBitSeqs(n int) [][]int {      
    seq := [][]int{{1}, {0}}
    for floor := 1; floor < n; floor++ {
        remember := [][]int{}
        for i := 0; i < len(seq); i++ {
            one := append(seq[i], 1)
            remember = append(remember, one)
            zero := append(seq[i], 0)
            remember = append(remember, zero)
        }
        seq = remember
    }
    return seq
}
```

playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/s40RS7qEKfL

problem is, when n = 4 or more, I get:

```
[[1 1 1 0] [1 1 1 0] [1 1 0 0] [1 1 0 0] [1 0 1 0] [1 0 1 0] [1 0 0 0] [1 0 0 0] [0 1 1 0] [0 1 1 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]]
```

Notice how they are repeating in pairs.

I have tried some debugging and I think it has something to do with how Go copy its slices when it needs to allocate more space.

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/index contains at least two articles which explain in detail how slices, arrays and append work (and what your problem is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slice is a view of an underlying array. If you have multiple slices working with the same underlying array, you may get unexpected results if you don't know how slices work.

```
one := append(seq[i], 1)
```

Say, `one` is a slice pointing to an array that has the capacity to hold the added element. Something like the following:

```
[ 1 1 . . .  ]
```

The array capacity is 5, with first two elements set to 1 (slice len=2). When you add another 1, it becomes:

```
[ 1 1 1 . .]
```

Then you do the following:

```
remember = append(remember, one)
```

With this, you added a slice pointing to the above array, with len=3 and capacity=5.

Then:

```
zero := append(seq[i], 0)
```

Remember that seq[i] is still pointing to the same array. Further, seq[i] has len=2. So the array becomes:

```
[ 1 1 0 . . ]
```

That is your `zero`. However, when you add that 0, you also changed the slice `one`. You end up with both `zero` and `one` pointing to `[1 1 0 . .]`.

Long story short: when you assign a slice to a variable, you assign the view to an array. If you modify the contents of the underlying array, the contents of the view also change.

To fix: create a new slice, copy data, and store that copy.

Comment: I see. so slices are like "super pointers" from C languages? each slice of an array contains the range of where it points to, the length, and i guess some more extra stuff?

Comment: Array, length, and capacity. The definitive guide about slices is: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: @MakingHandties: Also, compare `interface{}` with C's `void *`: an `interface{}` can hold any concrete type and is something like a "fat pointer" in a different way. It holds two units of information: the type of the concrete object that the `interface{}` value is holding-or-pointing-to, and the value that it is holding-or-pointing-to. So Go has 2-unit-wide "fat" types (interface) and 3-unit-wide "fat" types (slice). (We're not actually promised that interface is exactly 2 units wide, but it is in the current implementations. We are sort-of-promised that slices are 3 units wide.)